# How can I change <tr> to <thead>

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I specifically need thead tags in my program. When I use `System.Web.UI.WebControls;` it outputs header rows as `<tr>` tags instead of `<thead>` tags. Is there a way to change this so that it says `<thead>`?

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

 Table tbl = new Table();

 TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
 foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
 {
     TableCell th = new TableCell();
     th.Text = col.Caption;
     th.ID = "cellSize";
     thr.Controls.Add(th);
 }
 tbl.Controls.Add(thr);

 tbl.RenderControl(w);
 tableString = sw.ToString();
```

This outputs a row like `<tr><td></td></tr>`

Comment: Do you mean it puts `<tr>` tags instead of `<th>` tags?

Comment: You can go lower level and create your HTML via StringBuilder. This way you will have exact control over the tags.

Comment: tr tags should be one level lower than thead tags. thead and tbody tags should envelop tr tags.

Comment: @mason yes, it puts TR tags. and I need THEAD tags

Comment: You still need tr tags. The output you're showing is valid. I think what you mean is you want th tags instead of td tags. It should look like <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>

Comment: I think you're confused over the difference between `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<thead>` tags. `<thead>` is completely different, as the children of `<thead>` should be `<tr>` tags. The children of `<tr>` tags should be `<td>` (regular cell) or `<th>` (header cell) tags. That said, if you need fine grained control over the generated HTML, then don't use controls. Write HTML yourself, or find a library that's meant for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `TableHeaderCell` instead of `TableCell` in your `TableHeaderRow`. This will emit `<th>` tags intead of `<td>` tags in your header.

You can find information on `TableHeaderCell` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheadercell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I did try this. The reason I need it to use thead tags is that I'm using jquery datatables and that plugin requires those tags.